# processing id value inside loop with jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a basket list, here I show the total price by multiplying the price with the quantity with jquery in the price increase, but I cannot process the value in the span tag in the loop.

For example, I increase the amount of the product named "x", the product named "y" changes

span tag in foreach :

```
@foreach (var item in Islemler.GetSepet())
{
  <span id="toplamFiyat" class="badge rounded-pill badge-light-success">
  </span>  
  <input onchange="miktar(this)" data-idd="@item.ID" data-price="@item.SatisFiyat1" type="text" class="quantity-counter" value="@item.Miktar" />                
}
```

Javascript

```
     function miktar(t) {
            var id = ($(t).data('idd'));
            var fiyat = ($(t).data('price'));
            var miktar = $(t).val();
        
            getValue("/Home/SepetGuncelle",
                { 
                  stokID: id, 
                  StokMiktar: miktar, 
                  BirimFiyat: fiyat 
                },
                function (data, err) {
                    toplamFiyat = fiyat * miktar;
                    $("#tt").text("Toplam Fiyat: " + '₺'  
                                  + parseFloat(toplamFiyat, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,")
                                  .toString());

                })
```

Comment: Please fix the code and code format in the question. Create a [mcve]. It's hard to tell in this state what's the issue you're facing.

Comment: It would also be helpful to know what you mean by "cannot process". Are you getting an error? (If so, what is the error message?) Are you seeing unexpected behavior? (If so, what is your expected behavior?)

Comment: I have a <span> tag in the foreach whose id is the total price. I am changing the value of this span tag in jquery side. When I change it, how many <span> occurred in the foreach, they all change

Comment: For example, I have products called iphone 11 and iphone 12, these products come from foreach. In this foreach, there is price information in the <span> tag. I multiply the price information with the quantity on the jquery side and change the value again. Now when I change the product named iphone 12, iphone 11 also changes

Comment: Hi Ahmet, you should post a little more. At least the whole foreach loop and related spans or if necessary the whole html (if possible). It is difficult to say what is wrong in your code according to your post.

Comment: I've added all my code I can't handle the id li <span> tag which is #totalprice that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `span` ids should be unique, but in your code all your basket items have span with the same id, which is `toplamFiyat`. That's your problem. You can use something like this:

```
@foreach (var item in Islemler.GetSepet())
{
    <span id="toplamFiyat{@item.ID}" class="badge rounded-pill badge-light-success"></span>  
    <input onchange="miktar(this)" data-idd="@item.ID" data-price="@item.SatisFiyat1" type="text" class="quantity-counter" value="@item.Miktar" />
}
```

And your javascript should be:

```
function miktar(t) {
    var id = ($(t).data('idd'));
    var fiyat = ($(t).data('price'));
    var miktar = $(t).val();

    getValue("/Home/SepetGuncelle", 
        { stokID: id, StokMiktar: miktar, BirimFiyat: fiyat },
        function (data, err) {
            var toplamFiyat = fiyat * miktar;
            $("#toplamFiyat" + id).text("Toplam Fiyat: " + '₺' + parseFloat(toplamFiyat, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString());
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: $("#toplamFiyat" + id).text("Toplam Fiyat: " + '₺' + parseFloat(toplamFiyat, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+\.)/g, "$1,").toString()); **returning empty**